# script in /etc/update-motd.d/ not working

Tags: shell-script, ssh, login, motd

I have created a script `/etc/update-motd.d/foo`

```
#!/bin/sh
echo aaa
exit 0
```

I would like this script to be executed on ssh login, and display the output.

I have the folowing lines in my `/etc/pam.d/sshd`:

```
session    optional     pam_motd.so  motd=/run/motd.dynamic
session    optional     pam_motd.so noupdate
```

which I expected should execute that script on ssh login.

But that does not work, and nothing is printed on ssh login. The script is owned by root and has 755 permissions.

What else do I need to do?

I am using Debian 10.

Comment: Check if don't have the line `UsePAM` commented. Use `grep -i usepam /etc/ssh/sshd_config` if you see `#UsePAM yes` then edit the file and change it to `UsePAM yes`

Comment: @Edgar Magallon - That was exactly the problem. Do you want to make your comment into an answer, so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to be able to use Linux PAM modules in `ssh` you should uncomment the line (or add it if this one does not exist) `#UsePAM` present in file `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`.

To edit such file I suggest you use:

```bash
sudo -e /etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

Where `-e` is used to edit the file with root permissions.
The editor used by `-e` is determined by the environment variable `EDITOR` so you can set it to `EDITOR=nvim` for example, if you want to use neovim instead of the default editor (which is nano, AFAIK)

Answer (score -1):

You need to enable the executable bit on the file.

```
chmod +x path/to/your/file
```